# Typescript generic function accept object that has first argument as a key

Tags: typescript

I want to make a `function` that accepts a `string` first argument, and then will only accept a second `object` argument if it has the first argument as a key, with a `boolean` value:

```js
const checkFlag = (str:string, obj) => obj[str]
```

This works but is undesirable (putting the object generic first):

```js
const checkFlag = <K extends {[key:string]:boolean}, T extends keyof K>(str:T, obj:K) => obj[str]
```

leading to these results on Type Error:
[image]

[image]

What typings can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my answer:

```js
const checkFlag = <T extends string , K extends {[key in T]:boolean}>(str:T, obj:K) => obj[str]
```

leading to these Type Errors:
[image]
[image]